# dplyr join data frame in side a function using function arguments as by.x and by.y

Tags: r, join, dynamic, dplyr, refer

I wanted to do left_join inside a function using function arguments to tell the code which should be 'by.x' and 'by.y'. In the example below, I wanted to use 'a2' and 'a3' arguments of function 'aa' - in place of "x1" and "a" in the 'by' parameter. AM confused how to use benefits of rlang package here

```
aa <- function(a1,a2,a3){
  a1 %>% left_join(a1, by=c("x1"="a"))
}
xx<-data.frame(a=c(1:2), x1=c(2:3))
aa(xx,"x1","a")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, if you could post samples of input and output in your post with CODE TAGS it will be lot easier for use to understand more on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly and your goal is to be able to pass to the function the names of the columns you're joining by, the below should work:

```
aa <- function(a1,a2,a3){
  a1 %>% left_join(a1, by=setNames(a3, a2))
}

xx<-data.frame(a=c(1:2), x1=c(2:3))
aa(xx,"x1","a")
```

Specifying the columns by using `c(a2=a3)` wouldn't work in this situation and I replaced it with `setNames(a3, a2)`.